# Change the icon for a .NET executable post-build?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a .NET application that I produce several different versions - the exact same application but with different 'branding' (splash screen, name, etc.). I have all of those differences outside the main executable so they're picked up at runtime. However, I can't do this with the program icon because it's baked into the EXE file.

I'd like to avoid making lots of different projects just for the icon. Is there a way I can modify the icon for an already built .NET EXE? I have a feeling [ILDASM.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) and [ILAsm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx(VS.80).aspx) might be handy here, but I'm not sure what to do with the disassembled bits to change the icon ready to feed it into ILAsm.

Should I just use a script that modifies the original project file to use a new icon and re-build the whole thing?

Or maybe I'm going about this entirely the wrong way, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to change more than just the icon. So I'm using the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to generate a stub exe with all the correct bits that references the 'real' starting assembly and just calls it's version of 'main'.

Setting the correct icon for this was just a matter of using

```
var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
{
  GenerateExecutable = true,
  CompilerOptions = string.Format("/target:winexe /win32icon:\"{0}\"", iconPath)
  // ... other options ...
}
```

when calling:

```
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, new[] { sourceCode });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave you exe "unbranded" and keep your icons as separate files. During deployment, use the appropriate icon for the application shortcuts.

Comment: This is the option I was leaning towards, but I've ended up needing to change more than just the icon. So I'm now using the CodeDom to generate a stub exe with all the correct bits that will just call into the 'real' Main method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ResHacker.exe or XN Resource Editor.  I haven't used XN Resource Editor but have used ResHacker to change the icon resource in a PE.